# How to use pandas and numpy to compare two excel workbooks with multiple tabs with difference in the rows and columns in a single tab?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have two xlsx files that have multiple tabs. I need to compare values in each tab based on the tab name,**but in some tab there is a difference in the rows and columns** (e.g. sheet1 in file1 needs to be compared with sheet1 in file2 and so on). When I use the following code, **it will only compare and write the only for same numbers of rows and same number of columns**. Please help me figure out why all tabs do not get compared.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel('test_1.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
df2 = pd.read_excel('test_2.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

with pd.ExcelWriter('./Excel_diff.xlsx') as writer:
    for sheet, df1 in df1.items():
        # check if sheet is in the other Excel file
        if sheet in df2:
            df2sheet = df2[sheet]
            comparison_values = df1.values == df2sheet.values

            print(comparison_values)

            rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values == False)
            for item in zip(rows, cols):
                df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} → {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]], df2sheet.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

            df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This endeavor is non-trivial irrespective of tool or library.
However, when you get it going or need to validate your progress, Microsoft have already built a very useful and intuitive tool to compare workbooks quite nicely.  Consider using it to accompany your dev efforts: E[xcel Compare](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/compare-two-versions-of-a-workbook-by-using-spreadsheet-compare-0e1627fd-ce14-4c33-9ab1-8ea82c6a5a7e)